# Redirect domain with HTTPS directly from Domain registrar

Tags: redirect, https, dns

let's say I have a website on https://example.com and I want to migrate everything over https://newexample.com, I would like to do the 301 redirect via the domain registrar (ex. Namecheap). Is it possible to redirect from there also the https version?

The only thing I have been able to do is the redirect via htaccess, but that makes me have old domains forever set up on my server. I would prefer to do it directly from registrar and forget about it.

Thank you in advance,
Gabriel

Comment: That kind of functionality is not part of the DNS, but some name service providers might offer it, so you will have to check with your DNS provider.

Answer (score 0):

Recently ran into this exact issue. We moved some 301s off our server onto the registrar.  However, Google still had our HTTPS site indexed, and when people clicked those links from the SERP page, they would get an error because the Registrar was not setup with SSL certs for those domains.

One important point to remember is DNS does not (cannot) handle redirects. So what that means is the Registar simply has a server that it points the A record to, and that server has your domain setup in its web server (Apache/Nginx/etc) to handle the redirect.

While they *could* setup SSL for you, traditionally this would have cost them a decent amount of money. Now that certs can be free, it's possible some registrars could add this, but I find it highly unlikely they want to take on this responsibility.

So unfortunately at this time, if you need HTTPS redirects setup, you will have to keep it installed on your server, and keep the SSL certificate live on there as well.